# Json read error?

Tags: android

Hi friends I am getting the value from webservice while json value .I am storing in stringBuffer . I am getting the lot of value from webservice .so I am getting out of memory error .can any body tell how to avoid that?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You can allocate the StringBuffer with more amount of size, or try to implement paging or lazy loading..

But, with a lot of value, I think it's not good to use JSon

Answer (score 0):

Json is stored in memory and simply lot of data from server cause out of memory exception. Better idea is to download data in chunks and store in database.

To do it use [Jackson library](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) that support streaming data or [JsonReader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html) but it is only in Android 3.0.